# jquery to existing php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

im working on having a search result for list of bugs
im trying to use jquery but i m very new to jquery . im not able to produce the search result .
can someone help me or guide me how to produce a table based on the name entered 
here is my code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');
include('connection.php');
$result=mysql_query("select * from bug");
echo"BUG LIST";
echo "\n";
echo "<table border=1>";
echo"<tr><td>bugid</td><td>name</td><td>Description</td><td>Priority</td><td>Assigned to</td></tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo
"</td><td>" .$row['bugid'].
"</td><td>" . $row['name'] .
"</td><td>" .$row['description'].
"</td><td>" .$row['priority'].
"</td><td>" .$row['assign'].
"</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>


Delete BUG
<form action="delbug.php" method="post">
Enter bug id : <input type="text" name="bugid">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<a href="bugreport.php">Report New bug<br/></a>
```

the page table lists the  reported bugs

now i want to have a  filter box which alters the table contents and display only the bugs reported by specific user

i tried the code but it doesnt work

```
<form method="get">  
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
    <button class="btnSearch">Filter</button>  

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                 function search(){

                      var title=$("#search").val();

                      if(title!=""){
                        $("#result").html("<img alt="ajax search" src='ajax-loader.gif'/>");
                         $.ajax({
                            type:"post",
                            url:"search.php",
                            data:"title="+title,
                            success:function(data){
                                $("#result").html(data);
                                $("#search").val("");
                             }
                          });
                      }
                 }

                  $("#button").click(function(){
                         search();
                  });

                  $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
                     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                        search();
                      }
                  });
            });
        </script>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');
include('connection.php');
$name=$_POST['name'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from bug where name=$name ");
eche "<table border=1>";
echo"<tr><td>bugid</td><td>name</td><td>Description</td><td>Priority</td><td>Assigned to</td></tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo
"<tr><td>" .$row['bugid'].
"</td><td>" . $row['name'] .
"</td><td>" .$row['description'].
"</td><td>" .$row['priority'].
"</td><td>" .$row['assign'].
"</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: That code has several errors that will make it fail: it uses double quotes in a double-quoted string, it has typographical mistakes (eg: `eche` instead of `echo`), it uses deprecated functions like `mysql_*` (this will not make it fail, but it's not good either), and it is subject to SQL injection as the parameters are not processed before using them in the query

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //$(document).ready(function(){

                 function search(){
                    var title = $("#name").val();
                      if(title!=""){
                        //$("#result").html('<img alt="ajax search" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>');
                         $.ajax({
                            type:"post",
                            url:"search.php",
                            data:"title="+title,
                            success:function(data){
                                $("#result").html(data);
                                $("#search").val("");

                             }
                          });
                      }
                 }

                  $("#button").click(function(){
                         search();
                  });

                  $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
                     if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                        search();
                      }
                  });
           // });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
    <button class="btnSearch" onClick="search()">Filter</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code :

search.php file:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');
include('connection.php')
 $title=$_GET['title'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from bug where name = '".$title."'");
echo "<table border=1>";
echo"<tr><td>bugid</td><td>name</td><td>Description</td><td>Priority</td><td>Assigned to</td></tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo
"<tr><td>" .$row['bugid'].
"</td><td>" . $row['name'] .
"</td><td>" .$row['description'].
"</td><td>" .$row['priority'].
"</td><td>" .$row['assign'].
"</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: please check the browser console

Comment: tried bro its giving these errors     GET http://192.168.1.233/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js 
buglist.php:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ buglist.php:22
4buglist.php:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not definedsearch @ buglist.php:6onclick @ buglist.php:37

Comment: corrected the other errors now it is Uncaught ReferenceError: search is not defined